# How to compare an integer to see if it's equal to a certain number, plus or minus 2

Tags: c#, if-statement, range

I would like to be able to create an `if` statement that checks to see if `GlobalVars` is equal to 92 plus or minus 2.

I was just hoping there was a way I could do it without stating the range 90-94.. ie a 92 -/+ 2 equivalent.

I have the below code so far:

```
if (GlobalVars.myIP3 == 92 || GlobalVars.myIP3 == 93)
{ 
}
```

Comment: _"How would i do that?"_ -- do what? Create an `if` statement that compares `GlobalVars` to `92`, plus or minus `2`? Well, ignoring the fact that in your code `GlobalVars` does not appear to be an identifier that _could_ be compared to a numeric value such as `92`, you just _write the `if` statement_. Have you tried that? What _have_ you tried? What _specifically_ did you have trouble with? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Good questions are expected to show that you made an effort to solve your problem yourself, as well as a clear enough explanation to know what you need help with

Comment: you can use ```(GlobalVars.myIP3 >= 90 && GlobalVars.myIP3 <= 94)```

Comment: `x == 92 - 2 || x == 92 + 2`

Comment: Thanks Keith, yea i tried that, its a working solution, i would just hoping there was a way i could do it without stating the range 90-94.. ie a 92-/+ 2 equivalent....I am new to this language, and was just searching for examples, which i couldn't find, hence why i came to you guys.

Comment: 蕭為元 yes that will work also thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing provided for you in the .NET Framework, but you could write an extension method that does what you're looking for.

Create an extension method in a separate class:

```
public static class MathExt
{
    public static bool IsInRange(this int number, int target, int range)
    {
        return number >= target - range && number <= target + range;
    }
}
```

Then reference your new extension method as necessary:

```
if (GlobalVars.myIP3.IsInRange(92, 2))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is just Fantastic thank you very much Grant, legend!.. I wish i could upvote but i cant get my Popularity up over 15. But otherwise, definite solution to my my problem, Many Thanks